# Android write the whole logcat message in file

Tags: android, logging

I have a function which writes exception logs in a file on SD CARD.But the problem is that it's writing only the first line of it, without any information about on which line is thrown that exception and etc. Any ideas how to get the whole Log?

Save to file :

```
    public static void writeLogs(String text){
    File logFile = new File("sdcard/Documents/Public/Log/crash_logs.file");
       if (!logFile.exists())
       {
          try
          {
             logFile.createNewFile();
          } 
          catch (IOException e)
          {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
       try
       {
          //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
          BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
          buf.append("---START---");
          buf.newLine();
          buf.append(text);
          buf.newLine();
          buf.append("---END---");
          buf.newLine();
          buf.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Invoke :

```
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                rpc.writeLogs(e.toString());
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

e.toString doesn't provide the stack, try printStackTrace(writer or stream)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I ended up splitting e.toString() by \n and then wrote each line individually to my log.

Answer (score -1):

use println() instead of append.

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("your text file.txt"));
p.println(text);
```

Comment: [BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) has no `println()` method. Apart from that it would be great to provide a reason *why* this would be better.

Comment: sorry, haven't read about BufferedWriter before. but what I use in previous java se project is PrintWriter. please see updated answer.

Comment: also, e.toString might be different from the output of e.printStackTrace(). have you checked on the value of e.toString()?